# Request for open source program for finding reduced row echelon form of an augmented matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I have hundreds of augmented matrices in the following form:
$$\left(\begin{array}{cccc|c}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1& 2+\frac{4}{f}\\
a & b & c & d& 2\\
p & q & r & s& 2\\
m & n & k & l & 2
\end{array}\right),$$
where $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $p$, $q$, $r$, $s$ are known and $m$, $n$, $k$, $l$ are not known.

For example, $a=1$, $b=0$, $c=2$, $d=0$, $p=0$, $q=2$, $r=0$ and $s=2$, we have $$\left(\begin{array}{cccc|c}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1& 2+\frac{4}{f}\\
1 & 0 & 2 & 0& 2\\
0 & 2 & 0 & 2& 2\\
m & n & k & l & 2
\end{array}\right).$$
Then I need to compute its rref as follows:
$$\left(\begin{array}{cccc|c}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1& 2+\frac{4}{f}\\
1 & 0 & 2 & 0& 2\\
0 & 2 & 0 & 2& 2\\
m & n & k & l & 2
\end{array}\right)
\rightarrow
\left(\begin{array}{cccc|c}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0& \frac{8}{f}\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1& 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0& 1-\frac{4}{f}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & l-n & -\frac{f(n+k-2)+8m-4k}{f}
\end{array}\right)
$$
I have tried [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=reduced%20row%20echelon%20form%3A%20%7B%7B1%2C%201%2C%201%2C%201%2C%202%2B4%2Ff%7D%2C%20%7B1%2C%200%2C%202%2C%200%2C%202%7D%2C%20%7B0%2C%202%2C%200%2C%202%2C%202%7D%2C%20%7Bm%2C%20n%2C%20k%2C%20l%2C%202%7D%7D%2C%20l%3D%20n), but somehow it assumes $l\neq n$ even I insist $l=n$:

[image]

I have tried wxmaxima but it fails to do the task.

> I would like to know whether there is any open source program to do the computation without assuming $l\neq n$.

Comment: why don't you do simply https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=reduced+row+echelon+form%3A+%7B%7B1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+2%2B4%2Ff%7D%2C+%7B1%2C+0%2C+2%2C+0%2C+2%7D%2C+%7B0%2C+2%2C+0%2C+2%2C+2%7D%2C+%7Bm%2C+n%2C+k%2C+n%2C+2%7D%7D ?

Comment: Alternatively, you can add "assume" in front of "$l=n$" to get the same result.

Comment: If you want to insist that $l=n$, why not just replace $l$ by $n$ ?

Comment: If I replace $n$ by $l$ in wolframalpha as janmarqz did, I will get a trivial matrix without f. I want to find out the condition on f in terms of $m$, $n$, $k$, $l$ such that the system have infinite many solutions. Of course, I can do it by hand one by one. But hundreds of matrices spend me too much time and it is very easy to make mistakes.